# How can I find out the ClientID for my google appengine service account?

Tags: google-app-engine

from google website:

Delegating domain-wide authority to the service account

If your application accesses user data, the service account that you created needs to be granted access to the Google Apps domain’s user data that you want to access.

The following steps must be performed by an administrator of the Google Apps domain:

Go to your Google Apps domain’s Admin console.
Select Security from the list of controls.
 If you don't see Security listed, select More controls from the gray bar at the bottom of the page, then select Security from the list of controls. If you can't see the controls, make sure you're signed in as an administrator for the domain.

Select Show more and then Advanced settings from the list of options.

Select Manage API client access in the Authentication section.

**In the Client Name field enter the service account's Client ID.**
**Question: what is this equal to? I am using service account that comes with google appengine, not a manually created service account**

In the One or More API Scopes field enter the list of scopes that your application should be granted access to. For example, if your application needs domain-wide access to the Google Drive API and the Google Calendar API, enter: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive, https://www.googleapis.com/auth/calendar.

Click Authorize.

Answer (score 2):

Answer for 2019

(Just figured this out myself, so I hope this is accurate. )

Go to *Google APIs*, then under the *Service Accounts* section, click on the service account you wish to get the ID from and open its properties.

[(image) Step 1: Google APIs > Service Accounts](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ymtYy.png)

Afterwards, click the *View domain wide delegation ID* . This will open a popup sidebar with displaying the ID.
[(image) Step 2: Delegation ID](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fceAZ.png)

Answer (score 1):

You cannot have a Client ID related to an App Engine application, You need to create a Credential from the related page.
Go to https://cloud.google.com/console and select your project.

Go to the section *APIs & Auth* and the *Credentials*.

[image]

Or you can go directly from this url

```
https://console.developers.google.com/project/{your project name}/apiui/credential
```

Select *Create new Client ID*

[image]

and then select *Service Account* as Application type
[image]

You have now a *Client ID* to configure in ther Apps Dashboard

[image]

Comment: thanks for the detailed answer. i think its not correct though. the ClientID for the appengine service account should be myapp.appspot.com where myapp should be replaced with your application identifier.

Answer (score 0):

From looking at the credential file I downloaded when creating my service account, looks like the 'client id' may be the same as the 'unique id' of the service account.  thanks, google :(.